# How to dynamically reallocate a table of strings of unknown both their count and their sizes, in C?

Tags: c, string, memory, resize

**UPDATE 2**: *Dave added error-checking in his suggestion, I adopted it and added a bit extended functionality, in a separate answer.*

**UPDATE 1**: *Problem Solved (it was not the realloc() it was the fact that I was not allocating an extra table slot for the NULL termination... I've corrected it). See also Dave's suggestion in the 1st answer*

**Original Post**:

Is it possible to reallocate dynamically a completely unknown table of strings in c, without using intermediate data structures?

What I want to do is to make a func sarr_make_tokens() to tokenize an arbitrary c-string and return a (NULL terminated) table of c-string tokens.

For example, with s[] = "hello cruel world!" and calling: char **tokens = s_make_tokens(s, " \t!"); I'd like to get a NULL terminated table of tokens...

```
tokens[0] : "hello"
tokens[1] : "cruel"
tokens[2] : "world"
tokens[3] : NULL
```

The piece of code below fails (in the realloc() line I guess) but I cannot think of the size I should pass to it, in order to preserve any already stored tokens.

Is it possible at all, or do I have to first obtain the number of tokens with an strok() loop on a local copy of s, then malloc as many slots in the tokens table and then apply another strtok() loop in order to store the actual tokens in the table?

I could use an intermediate linked list for storing the tokens, before copying them to the tokens table, but if there is a way to use realloc with the correct size would be so much better!

I would appreciate any help! Here is the problematic code... actually it works but seg-faults when trying to free() the obtained tokens table in the caller function.

```
#define S_FREE(p) \
    do \
        if ( (p) ) { \
            free( (p) ); \
                (p) = NULL; \
        } \
while (0)

/* --------------------------------------------- */
int sarr_free( char *sarr[] )
{
    register char **cpp = sarr;

    /* sanity check */
    if ( !sarr ) { errno = EFAULT; return 0; }

    while ( *cpp )
        free( *cpp++ );
    free( sarr );

    return 1;           /* TRUE                                   */
}


/* --------------------------------------------- */
char **sarr_make_tokens( char *s, const char *delims )
{
    char **tokens = NULL, **ppchar = NULL;
    size_t toksize = 0;
    register char *cp = NULL;
    register int i=0, j=0;

    /* sanity checks */
    if ( !s || !delims ) { errno = EFAULT; return NULL; }
    if ( !*s || !*delims ) { errno = EINVAL; return NULL; }

    i = 0;
    cp = strtok( s, delims );
    while ( cp != NULL )
    {
            /* add a new slot in the array */
            ppchar = realloc( tokens, (i+1) * sizeof(char *) );
            if ( !ppchar ) {
                    for (j=i-1; j > -1; j--)
                            free( tokens[j] );
                    S_FREE( tokens );
                    errno = ENOMEM;
                    return NULL;
            }
            tokens = ppchar;

            /* make room for the token & copy it into the slot */
            toksize = strlen( cp ) + 1;
            tokens[i] = calloc( toksize, sizeof(char) );
            if ( !tokens[i] ) {
                    for (j=i-1; j > -1; j--)
                            free( tokens[j] );
                    free( tokens );
                    errno = ENOMEM;
                    return NULL;
            }
            memcpy( tokens[i], cp, toksize );

            /* get next token */
            cp = strtok( NULL, delims );

            i++;
    }

    if ( i != 0 ) {         /* while-loop run at least once             */
            ppchar = realloc( tokens, (i+1) * sizeof(char *) );
            if ( !ppchar )
                /* handle error here */
            tokens = ppchar;
            tokens[ i ] = NULL; /* ... NULL terminate the array of tokens   */
    }

    else                /* while-loop did not run at all            */
            errno = ERANGE;     /* ... flag failure of 1st strtok()         */

    return tokens;

}
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then after some time, mark it as accepted rather than add the *SOLVED* to the header. That's not "standard" on StackOverflow.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm on to it right now, thanks!

Comment: Can't do it yet, because... "Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

    * Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 4 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's rather easy... Using `strtok()`, `strdup()`, and `realloc()`, the function is rather simple.

```
//EDIT: Now handles errors.
char **tok(char *s, char *delim)
{
    char *str, **arr, **ap;
    int cap=3, fill=0;
    if((str=strdup(s))==NULL) //in case s is read-only.
         goto NoMem;
    if((arr = malloc(cap*sizeof(char*)))==NULL)
         goto NoMem;
    for(s=strtok(str, delim); s; s=strtok(NULL, delim)){
        if(cap<=fill+1)
            if(ap = realloc(arr, (cap=(cap*3)/2)*sizeof(char*)))
                 arr=ap;
            else 
                 goto NoMem;
        if((arr[fill++] = strdup(s))==NULL)
            goto NoMem;
        arr[fill] = NULL;
    }
    free(str);
    return arr;
NoMem:
    if(str) free(str); 
    if(arr){
        for(ap=arr; *ap; ap++)
            free(*ap);
        free(arr);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

By resizing the array 150% each time it is about to overflow, only `log(n)` resizes are needed, and the space efficiency is still better than any linked list.

Comment: This seems pretty cool, thanks! However, strdup() is not a standard ANSI C func (there are lots of free(str) missing too, I think).

Comment: Where do you thing I'm forgetting to `free()`?

Comment: I was referring to the original version of your post :) Btw, I just tried your code with a custom strdup(const char *src){ char *s = NULL;
 size_t ssize = 0;

 /* sanity check */
 if ( !src ) { errno = EFAULT; return NULL; }

 ssize = strlen( src ) + 1;
 if ( !(s = malloc(ssize)) ) {
  errno = ENOMEM;
  return NULL;
 }

 return memcpy( s, src, ssize );
} and it seems to get into an infinite loop in the last line of the loop: arr[fill++] = strdup(s);
... it iterates properly once but then goes into infinite loop... same thing with both mingw gcc & pelles-c on Win7

Comment: Oh, you have changed it from strdup(str) to strdup(s)... so, let me check again.

Comment: Now its fine, nice one! Add the missing semicolon at the realloc() line so it is complete :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the realloc() after all, but because I was NOT allocating an extra table slot for the NULL termination, before exiting the function (I have corrected it, and erased the relevant text in the original post).

A more elegant (but not prortable) solution was also suggested by Dave: [How to dynamically reallocate a table of strings of unknown both their count and their sizes, in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078710/how-to-dynamically-reallocate-a-table-of-strings-of-unknown-both-their-count-and/8081308#8081308)

Thank you all for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Adopting Dave's suggestion, and extending a little bit the functionality of the original function so it lets the programmer to decide whether s should be treated as read-only (slower) or not (faster), via an extar parameter, I've come up with the following... is a bit redundant in the error-checking, which kinda contradict the "faster" claim, but ok I  haven't given it lots of thought yet... but hopefully it's bug-free.

```
#define S_FREE(p)            \
    do                       \
        if ( (p) ) {         \
            free( (p) );     \
            (p) = NULL;      \
        }                    \
    while (0)

#define SARR_BACKFREE(sarr, ifailed)        \
    do {                                    \
        register int i=0;                   \
        for (i=(ifailed)-1; i > -1; i--)    \
            S_FREE( (sarr)[i] );            \
        S_FREE( (sarr) );                   \
    } while(0)

/* -------------------------------------- */
char *s_strdup( const char *src )
{
    char *s = NULL;
    size_t ssize = 0;

    /* sanity check */
    if ( !src ) { errno = EFAULT; return NULL; }

    ssize = strlen( src ) + 1;
    if ( !(s = malloc(ssize)) ) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    return memcpy( s, src, ssize );
}

/* -------------------------------------- */
char **sarr_make_tokens( char *s, char *delims, const int readonly )
{
    char *str = NULL, *cp = NULL;
    int cap = 3, itok = 0;
    char **sarr = NULL, **ppchar = NULL;

    /* sanity checks */
    if ( !s || !delims ) { errno = EFAULT; return NULL; }
    if ( !*s || !*delims ) { errno = EINVAL; return NULL; }

    /* treat s as a string literal? */
    if ( readonly ) {
        if ( (str = s_strdup( s )) == NULL )
            goto ret_nomem;
    }
    else    str = s;

    /* allocate table of strings sarr */
    if ( (sarr = malloc( cap * sizeof(char *) )) == NULL )
        goto ret_nomem;

    /* tokenize str and store tokens in sarr */
    for ( cp=strtok(str, delims); cp; cp=strtok(NULL, delims) )
    {
        if( cap <= itok+1 )
        {
            ppchar = realloc(sarr, (cap=(cap*3)/2) * sizeof(char *) );
            if ( !ppchar )
                goto clean_and_ret_nomem;
            sarr = ppchar;
        }

        if ( (sarr[ itok ] = s_strdup( cp )) == NULL )
            goto clean_and_ret_nomem;

        itok++;
    }

    /* NULL terminate sarr */
    sarr[ itok ] = NULL;

    if ( readonly )
        S_FREE( str );
    return sarr;

clean_and_ret_nomem:
    SARR_BACKFREE(sarr, itok);
ret_nomem:
    if ( readonly )
        S_FREE( str );          /* S_FREE() works ONLY if str != NULL */
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return NULL;
}
```